# Building reverse engineered project

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I learn development for android, I would like to see how certain application is built, I also would like to adjust its UI controls positions for sole use.

So, I decompiled the application and try to build it with Eclipse bundle. I got an apk file built, but when I start it it produces the exception `"java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider iching.android.contentprovider.DivinationProvider"`

But I see the file `src/iching/android/contentprovider/DivinationProvider.java` which contains missing class definition:

```
package iching.android.contentprovider;

import android.content.ContentProvider;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.UriMatcher;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder;
import android.net.Uri;
import iching.android.persistence.IChingSQLiteDBHelper;

public class DivinationProvider extends ContentProvider
{
```

1. How can I get compiled apk which can't find a class, used in it?
2. Why does not it find the class declared in properly placed source file?

**UPDATE**:
I found java compiler was disabled, so bin/classes remain empty on build finish

**UPDATE2**:
Yep there was a lot of errors when I enabled javac.

Comment: You just "assume" your decompiler successfully decompiled the entire .apk with all its .class files in it so youre able to rebuild and run it again... i hardly doubt that in the first place while in your case it is possible you just dont have the dependency containing iching.android.contentprovider packed to the rest of the application correctly.

Comment: I expected errors on building project, but certainly did't expect built apk could not find a dependency written in main activity as import. How that can be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I give it a shot to answer your questions but i have to admit its half guessing since i dont see actual results of your decompiling/ running attempts:

0.) Make sure the app (.apk) you have runs as it is (e.g. "it works" as delivered from its producer)

1.) Since decompiling (even in Java) is not trivial as soon as there is complex (or "obfuscated") input data it is very likely the decompiled source will not compile.
=> In 99% of the cases decompiling is used to understand how something work using static code analysis rather than "just run it".

So "the lack of skills" of decompilers CAN lead to what you call "compiled apk which can't find a class, used in it". Mostly however because Class-dependencys were not decompiled correctly.

2.) Because it is not there. It is that simple. Assumed the decompiling worked properly (it looks as it would since you dont have any compile time issues) you are just missing the dependency iching.android.contentprovider. Recheck all of the 3th party librarys are getting attached to your final build-output (i assume a .apk file) correctly. Unfortunately i dont know how you are building your project.

Comment: First of all - thank you for explanations! To build it I select project/clean, then project/build. I also tried to manually delete `gen` and `bin` directories. After I'd built the project these dirs appeared. I concluded that build was successful.

Comment: Seems I don't get right essential things about building apk. As I understand that process, the project simply could not be built if it can't find the class definition.